# Alternating time-frames and seemingly non related chapters

Tags: fiction, plot-structure

- Chapter 1. A child is kidnapped, her friend (same age) is the protagonist is mentioned, she trie so send him a letter but it never reaches him.
- Chapter 2. Takes place 10 years later but doesn't mention the girl from Chapter 1
- Chapter 3. Back to 1953 and we discover where the girl has been taken (traffickers)
- Chapter 4. Switches back to 1963 and brings back the protagonist, but the girl isn't mentioned. It follow Chapter 2.
- Chapter 5. Switches back to 1953 again and the villains are kidnapping again, but the girl from Chapter 1 isn't mentioned.
- Chapter 5. Goes back to 1953 again and we find that the kidnapped girl is supposed to be dead (but in actual fact she's still in the hands of the kidnappers).

All the chapters from here on are either POV switches, scene switches or time swiches alternating, but right at the end, we find the girl alive and she leads the protagonist to her captors. Suspense/Thriller

Maybe I should mention her in Chapter 2 (we find she was supposed to have been killed in an 'accidental' fire in Chapter 5 - but in actual fact the fire is only a cover up.) Perhaps an inner thought as a fire engine passes his car?

Comment: Your question seems a bit vague. What are you trying to ask here? Is your question about whether or not you should mention her in chapter 2?

Comment: I made a few changes. The protagonist mentions her in several chapters. Then when she sees no way to escape she gets Stockholm Syndrome until one day she gets a chance at escape and takes it. Goes to the protagonist and leads him to the trafficker's HQ, begs him not to kill her captor, but he's already dead, someone else killed him already. The protagonist destroys all the other pervs, Girl start a new life.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

1. If you plan to switch forth and back, make sure you provide any possible clue for the reader to know when and where they are.
2. provide both meaningful and not meaningful connections between the two plotlines. The fire-truck is one, but also sunsets on the road, similar places, people doing similar things (e.g. smoking, driving, eating a burger, looking at the sunset on the road)
3. Force the connection. Reference newspapers cutouts, TV news, people conversations mentioning the affair from 10 years prior.
4. most important, show the reader who is the character that they should be rooting for and why. It is dissatisfying to read a story and realize that we did not care about any of the characters despite their terrible ordeals.